# Обращение к свойствам и методам дочернего окна

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Делфи осваивал давно, а сейчас спустя промежуток несколько лет забылись некоторые вещи. Есть такая проблема. На главной форме (приложения MDI) формирую код по созданию дочернего окна:

```
//// Клиенты
procedure TFormMain.CreateChildFormClient
         (const childName : string);
  var Child: TFormClient;
begin
  Child:= TFormClient.Create(Application);
  Child.Caption := childName;
end;
```

В этом окне "Клиенты" (FormClient) в коде идет вызов модального окна по кнопке. То есть стандартно так:

```
 with FormEditClient do
  begin
    ...
    ShowModal;
  end;
```

Далее из этого модального окна FormEditClient тоже по событию клика кнопки пытаюсь вызвать метод из формы FormClient (дочернего окна по отношения к родительскому контейнеру, но вызывающего по отношению к форме FormEditClient). В итоге я получаю ошибку памяти, после вызова стандартного даже метода, к примеру, такого:

```
FormClient.FormShow(Sender);
```

Получаю такое окошко ошибки:

[image]

С MDI практически не работал, потому нужен совет, как обойти эту ситуацию, чтобы не допускать этих исключительных ошибок памяти.

Comment: @IntegralAL, а FormEditClient у Вас обычное окно или MDI?

Comment: Когда то разрабатывал MDI приложение посмотрю как у меня идет вызов ShowModal, но точно скажу, что окно которое вызывается модально не может быть MDI окном

Comment: Да точно, чтобы окно вызвать ShowModal, оно не должно быть MDI, вот как у меня сделано:

    procedure TfrmMain.mmHandbookClientClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      frmClientList: TfrmClientList;
    begin
    frmClientList := TfrmClientList.Create(Application);
    frmClientList.ShowModal;
    end;

И не забудьте убрать эту форму из автоматически создаваемых.

Comment: Ошибки типа `Read of adress 00000000` обычно возникают при попытке обратиться к объекту, которого нет (`=nil`). В строке `FormClient.FormShow(Sender);` скорее всего `FormClient = nil` или `Sender = nil`. Вы их проверяли на существование?

Comment: @IntegralAL Выложите максимально упрощенный код для воспроизведения ошибки. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: @IntegralAL, что за объект `FormBookHelp`? где **вы** его создаете? Потому что delphi создавать его не будет, если вы его уберете из auto-create forms. И как у вас передается этот `FormBookHelp` в модальное окно? Как глобальная переменная? А что будет если создать 10 одинаковых модальных форм, на какое окно будет ссылаться ваша переменная `FormBookHelp`, а если одно из них закрыть, `FormBookHelp` будет равно `nil` или это будет ссылка на несуществующий объект?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я же создаю его в самом начале на главной форме. Это про FormBookHelp. Child:= TFormBookHelp.Create(Application); (это MDI дочерняя форма) А модальная форма TFormHelp создается в проекте при старте один раз, она и есть модальная форма. Насчет того что FormBookHelp неоднозначна на модальной форме понял. Спасибо. Как тогда устранить такую двусмысленность? По HWND обращаться к окну Mdi?

Comment: `var Child: TFormClient;` после выполнения процедуры ссылки на это окно у вас не будет. нигде. `FormBookHelp` указывает неизвестно на что. Вопрос я задавал про нее.

Comment: Еще раз, `FormBookHelp` ссылается на несуществующий объект. Никакие FormBookHelp, FormBookHelp_1 и т.д. в системе не регистрируются, тут это вообще ни при чем. Не совсем понятно зачем нужны hwnd если у вас есть все что необходимо, просто вы нигде не сохраняете никакие ссылки. Child можно сохранить. Можно передать Self при открытии модального окна. Можно [и правильнее] обрабатывать результат работы модального окна (взывая методы) в вызывающем окне, глядя на ModalResult и так далее...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробовал я запустить ваш код из комментариев. Вот в этом месте:

```
procedure TFormBookHelp.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormHelp.ShowModal;
end;
```

`FormHelp` должен быть в списке форм создаваемых автоматически, либо вам его нужно создать самостоятельно перед обращением к нему. Иначе получите AV.
Если добавить эту форму в создаваемые автоматически, то все работает.

[image: Делаем раз]

[image: Делаем два]

Unit1 (главная форма):

```
uses
  Unit2;

procedure TForm1.bt1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Child: TFormBookHelp;
begin
  Child := TFormBookHelp.Create(Application);
  Child.Caption := 'Помощь по программе';
end;
```

Unit2 (Дочерняя форма):

```
uses
  Unit3;

procedure TFormBookHelp.bt1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormHelp.ShowModal;
end;


procedure TFormBookHelp.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TFormBookHelp.Test;
begin
  MessageDlg('Проверка!!', mtError, [mbOK], 1);
end;
```

Unit3 (Модальная форма):

```
uses
  Unit2;

procedure TFormHelp.bt1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormBookHelp.Caption := 'test';
  FormBookHelp.Test;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я решил уже сам проблему). В любом случае плюсую ответ и добавляю вам рейтинг за помощь!